# Trashed Postgres template1

Tags: postgresql, templates

I was screwing around in psql and renamed the template0 and template1 before realizing their usage.  Now, I am getting a "permission denied to copy database 'template1'" from inside psql and form command-line when I try to recreate template1.

To save time, is there anything else I need to know about template1 vis a vis OS read/write permissions in /data/base or granting on template1 etc.

TIA

Answer (score 7):

You have to tell PostGreSQL that `template1` is a template. If you don't, you won't be allowed to copy it if you aren't the owner:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template1';
```

I had to read the source code of `/src/backend/commands/dbcommands.c` (found by Google) to understand that. It says:

```
/*
 * Permission check: to copy a DB that's not marked datistemplate, you
 * must be superuser or the owner thereof.
 */
if (!src_istemplate)
{
        if (!pg_database_ownercheck(src_dboid, GetUserId()))
                ereport(ERROR,
                                (errcode(ERRCODE_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGE),
                                 errmsg("permission denied to copy database \"%s\"",
                                                dbtemplate)));
}
```

And I found how to do it [on a blog](http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/05/postgresql-template-databases-to.html)

[my similar problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/159646/postgresql-encoding-problem-when-createdb-and-lc-allc/159859)

Answer (score 2):

How have you tried "to recreate template1"?

The easiest would be to drop the "template1" schema and recreate it from the "template0" schema. That is - if "template0" is still there.

More - [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You renamed the two databases? Maybe this will do what you need:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE, datname = 'template0' WHERE datname = 'current_template0_name';

UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE, datname = 'template1' WHERE datname = 'current_template1_name';
```